# Debugging C# MVC3 in visual studio : can i stop session data from clearing each time i re-start debugging?

Tags: c#, session

Each time when I stop debugging on localhost and start again, session data gets cleared. So, I have to log- out and log-in again to reach same point. This has become a pain because I have to go through the whole log-in process to reach the page that I was working on.

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `InProc` session state management (the default), then you're going to be out of luck.  Whenever the IIS worker process restarts (when you start debugging), the session state is cleared.  The advantage to `InProc`, of course, is that it runs in memory, so it's faster.

However, you could switch to using a state server or a database to manage the sessions.  Those both run out-of-process, meaning they don't get cleared when IIS restarts, or when you start debugging.

- See [This Microsoft article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732412(v=ws.10).aspx) for setting up a state server to manage sessions.
- See [This Microsoft article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753897(v=ws.10).aspx)  for setting up a SQL server for managing sessions.

Or perhaps, an alternative could be to use the `#if DEBUG` directive to hard-code and pre-populate a username and password during the login process?  That could at least save typing time :)